# How different pointer affect each other?

Tags: c, pointers, queue, dereference

*Feel free to tag this post as a duplicate because I couldn't find any answer for my question*

Here's the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct queue
{
    int val;
    struct queue *next;
} queue;
queue *head, *tail, *h1, *t1;

void enqueue (queue **a, queue **b, queue *c)
{
    if (*a) *b=(*b)->next=c;
    else *a=*b=c;
}

void add (int val)
{
    queue *node=(queue*) malloc (sizeof (queue));
    node->val=val, node->next=NULL;
    
    enqueue (&head, &tail, node);
    enqueue (&h1, &t1, node);
}

int main (void)
{
    add (1);
    add (2);
    add (3);
    add (4);
    
    queue *node=head, *test=h1;
    while (node) printf ("%d ", node->val), node=node->next; puts ("");
    
    head->val=99;
    printf ("%d\n", h1->val);
    
    node=head;
    while (node) printf ("%d ", node->val), node=node->next; puts ("");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of printing out

```
1 2 3 4 
1
99 2 3 4
```

it prints out

```
1 2 3 4
99
99 2 3 4
```

*Changing* `h1->val` *to* `test->val` *produces the same output*

Why and how `h1` is somehow *connected* to `head`?

I just tried something and I'm getting more confused
`printf ("%p %p\n", head, h1);` prints out the same thing, why is that, shouldn't it be different?

Comment: Do you use comma operator on purpose? `node->val=val, node->next=NULL;`

Comment: You enqueue exacly the same nodes into both queues. Therefore `head` and `h1` point to the same node. How could they not be connected?

Comment: @Gerhardh Ah yes I see, I just figured it out too. I moved `malloc` to `enqueue()` and it seems that the problem is fixed.

Comment: Style comment: newlines are cheap — use them.  Don't put multiple statements on a single line.  Especially, don't put a loop control statement, the loop body, and another statement all on a single line in ordinary code (macros are different, but even there, use space — and backslashes — liberally).   You have `while (node) printf ("%d ", node->val), node=node->next; puts ("");` several times.  The comma operator is necessary given what you're doing, but otherwise undesirable.  Write a function and call it to do the job since you write the code out several times anyway.

Comment: Also, adding a single allocated node to two separate queues will give you memory management problems when you get around to freeing the data.  If the two queues are always the same, why do you have both queues (one is sufficient).  If the two queues are different, how do you know whether to free a given node when you release the data in the queue (because it might still be in use in the other queue, or might already have been released by the other queue).  You should almost certainly create separate nodes to be put on separate queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you added the first value to the queue the both pointers `head` and `h1` point to the created node due to this statement within the function `enqueue`.

```
void enqueue (queue **a, queue **b, queue *c)
{
    if (*a) *b=(*b)->next=c;
    else *a=*b=c;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

because the function was called two times for the same node and the pointers `head` and `h1`.

```
void add (int val)
{
    queue *node=(queue*) malloc (sizeof (queue));
    node->val=val, node->next=NULL;
    
    enqueue (&head, &tail, node);
    enqueue (&h1, &t1, node);
}
```

The both pointers were assigned with the same value stored in the pointer `node`.

After that the pointers were not changed because this statement in enqueue

```
    else *a=*b=c;
```

did not get the control anymore.

So you can use either pointer to change the pointed node.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows what occurs under the hood.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int val = 1;
    int *p1, *p2;
    
    p1 = &val;
    p2 = &val;
    
    *p1 = 99;
    
    printf( "val = %d\n", *p2 );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
val = 99
```

That is the both pointers `p1` and `p2` point to the same variable `val`. So you can use either pointer to access the pointed object.